# Placing two buttons on the same line in HTML

Tags: html, css

Here is my login form:

[image: login page image]

As you can see the sign in and register buttons are on **separate lines**. I want them on the same line.

I placed register button code in the same paragraph element as sign in. It appeared on same line no doubt but when I click register it's asking me to fill out the username and password. How do I fix this?

This is my code:

```
<form method="post" > 
    <p><input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" style="margin:10px" autofocus required></p>  
    <p><input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" style="margin:10px" required></p>
    <p><input class="swd-button" type="submit" value="Sign In"></p>
</form>
<a href="register.html"><button class="swd-button">Register</button></a>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `<button>` instead an `<a>`.

Comment: Your html cod is fixed

Comment: Do you want the message to be thrown or not??

Comment: @user1069186 : Please see my updated answer.. Both the issues are solved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply re-arrange as follows and add a type to your button :

```
<form method="post" > 

    <p>
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" style="margin:10px" autofocus required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" style="margin:10px" required>
    </p>
    <p>
       <input class="swd-button" type="submit" value="Sign In">
       <a href="register.html"><button type="button" class="swd-button">Register</button></a>
    </p>

</form>
```

Normally if you add a `button` inside a form, it will take it as a submit button to trigger submit the form. So you need to specify it as `type="button"`.

Demo : http://jsbin.com/EjEbihUDu/2/

Comment: please look at the question again. have said i tried this. it isn't working. check your fiddle itself and click register button. it asks for username and password. which is not at all related for registering

Comment: Hey Roy M J it works!!!! great. thanks. you are awesome. thanks a lot. so simple it was. had to include type="button" in button element. wow!

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is that the button inside your link is intercepting click events. That's why it doesn't work when you put the second button as a sibling to the first.

To fix this, I suggest you remove the button from the link, style the link to *look* like a button and move it back into the same paragraph as the "Sign in" button, with both set to have `display: inline-block`.

**Here's the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/u3v2e/).**

**HTML:**

```html
<form method="post" > 
    <p><input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" style="margin:10px" autofocus required></p>  
    <p><input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" style="margin:10px" required></p>
    <p>
        <button class="swd-button" type="submit">Sign In</button>
        <a class="swd-button" href="register.html">Register</a>
    </p>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.swd-button {
    background: #11c3ff linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #009bcf);
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Added:

```
.swd-button {
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2es59/

Comment: why does this deserve a DV?

Answer (score 0):

Just put your register button inside the `<p>` tag

```
<p><input class="swd-button" type="submit" value="Sign In">
    <a href="register.html"><button class="swd-button">Register</button></a>
 </p>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DnpVr/)

Comment: please look at the question again. have said i tried this. it isn't working. check your fiddle itself and click register button. it asks for username and password. which is not at all related for registering

Comment: @user1069186 : no. it would work. if you click the register button it will redirect to register.html page. it would not ask for username and password.. i'm sure..

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" > 
<p><input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" style="margin:10px" autofocus required></p>  
<p> <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" style="margin:10px" required></p>
<div><input class="swd-button" type="submit" value="Sign In">

</form>
<a href="register.html"><button class="swd-button">Register</button></a></div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eL3cH/)

Comment: sorry. thats wrong. <form><div></form></div> is wrong way of coding

Answer (score 0):

add class to the element that `style="display:inline-block;"`

Comment: That's a style not a class.

Answer (score 0):

simply use table tag and try to do like this...

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="Login"></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Register"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

you can create all elements in a table for suitable view.

Comment: sorry. but using table for layout is 1990s and early 2000 style. table is only for tabular data. i repeat table should be used only for tabular data

Comment: ya, but you want the same thats y i suggested you.
and i suggested as i know.

Answer (score 0):

i got my answer. thanks to Roy M J. had to include just the type attribute type="button" in button element.

Like this:

```
<a href="register.html"><button class="swd-button" type="button">Register</button></a>
```

so the full working code is:

```
<form method="post" > 
<p><input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" style="margin:10px" autofocus required></p>  
<p> <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" style="margin:10px" required></p>
<p><input class="swd-button" type="submit" value="Sign In">
    <a href="register.html"><button class="swd-button" type="button">Register</button></a>
</p>
</form>
```